# How OAuth 2.0 Configuration is different from In-bound policies settings in Azure API Management?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-functions, microservices, azure-api-management

I'm developing a serverless micro services application in Azure.

In-order to securing the APIs, I have registered both Service & Client Application with Azure AD and grand API access to client app.

So, In API Management instance I have updated the in-bound policies (to Verify JWT token) based on Azure AD configuration. Now its working as expected.

But my question is without adding any configuration in API Management console "OAuth 2.0" section, how its working?

How OAuth 2.0 configuration is different from In-bound policies settings in Azure API Management?

Answer (score 1):

The blade for `OAuth 2.0` (and `OpenID Connect`) are to configure providers which powers the Developer Portal experience.

After defining the providers in these blades, APIs have to be assigned these providers for them to show up in the Developer Portal (in the `Try It` pages).

> Support for OAuth in the new developer portal is not available *yet*. [This issue tracks the feature](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/208).

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer. OAuth 2.0 Config required only for to use the oauth services in developer portal and consoles.[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942953/azure-api-management-is-oauth2-server-configuration-mandatory?rq=1)